# Deploy R markdown document on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, markdown, shiny, kaggle

I'm trying to deploy an R markdown document on the shinyapp.io server.

I have followed the steps as described [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/rmd-integration.html).
However, step 8 indicates the presence of a "deploy" button. This button is missing.

As an alternative I have tried :

1. to open a new R script
2. Navigate to the Working Directory for my .Rmd file
3. Ran the following command: `deployApp( appName = "Titanic")`

Logs indicated everything was being uploaded correctly. However my [destination page](https://glennterprise.shinyapps.io/Kaggle-Titanic) indicated 'not found'.

My questions:

1. Why did the 'deploy' button not show?
2. Why does my page indicate 'not found'?

Below you can find the header I used in the markdown document.

```
title: "KAGGLE - TITANIC SURVIVAL ANALYSIS"

output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    theme: spacelab
    number_sections: true
runtime: shiny
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Solved - An update to the latest version of R + the shiny library enabled these features.

Comment: Post as answer with version numbers and accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue solved with R Studio version

```
Version 0.99.451 – © 2009-2015 RStudio, Inc.
```

!Note: In the newest version the `deploy` button has been replaced with `Publish`
This has not been adapted in the official shiny documentation yet. The screenshot below is the view you get once a first publish (formerly called `deploy`) action has been taken.

[image: Publish]